# MSAL-SSO Authentication not communicating to different apps built in different framework

Tags: ios, swift, xamarin, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-msal

We have Mobile Application built in Xamarin and Swift. We recently implemented SSO using Azure AD and MSAL. SSO is working ok, if you sign-in from Xamarin app you will be automatically sign-in to Swift app. And if you sign-in from Swift app you will automatically sign-in to Xamarin App. The problem now is if you logout to swift app, and go back to Xamarin App to login. The SSO doesn't work, you don't automatically login in to Swift App.

Xamarin Code:

```
 public async Task<bool> SignInAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
            var authResult = await _pca
                .AcquireTokenSilent(Scopes, firstAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();                
            return true;
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException)
        {
            try
            {
                // This means we need to login again through the MSAL window.
                var authResult = await _pca.AcquireTokenInteractive(Scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
                                            .WithUseEmbeddedWebView(false)
                                            //.WithParentActivityOrWindow(App.UIParent)
                                            .ExecuteAsync();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex2.ToString());
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Xamarin Sign-out

```
public async Task SignOutAsync(bool isFromAutoLogout = false)
    {
        try
        {
            var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();

            // Go through all accounts and remove them.
            while (accounts.Any())
            {
                await _pca.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
                accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Swift Login

```
 func callLoadAcct() {

    initWebViewParams()

    self.loadCurrentAccount { (account) in



        guard let currentAccount = account else {



            // We check to see if we have a current logged in account.

            // If we don't, then we need to sign someone in.

            self.acquireTokenInteractively()

            return

        }



        self.acquireTokenSilently(currentAccount)

    }

}



typealias AccountCompletion = (MSALAccount?) -> Void
    

    func loadCurrentAccount(completion: AccountCompletion? = nil) {

        guard let applicationContext = MSALManager.shared.applicationContext else { return }

        let msalParameters = MSALParameters()
        msalParameters.completionBlockQueue = DispatchQueue.main

        applicationContext.getCurrentAccount(with: msalParameters, completionBlock: { (currentAccount, previousAccount, error) in

            if let error = error {
                return
            }

            if let currentAccount = currentAccount {

                self.updateCurrentAccount(account: currentAccount)

                if let completion = completion {
                    completion(MSALManager.shared.currentAccount)
                }

                return
            }

            MSALManager.shared.accessToken = ""
            MSALManager.shared.originalAuthTokenExpire = nil
            self.updateCurrentAccount(account: nil)

            if let completion = completion {
                completion(nil)
            }
        })
    }
```

Swift Sign-out

```
  func signOut() {

    self.appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate

    guard let applicationContext = MSALManager.shared.applicationContext else { return }

    guard let account = MSALManager.shared.currentAccount else { return }



    do {

        MSALManager.shared.webViewParameters = MSALWebviewParameters(authPresentationViewController: self.appdelegate.window?.rootViewController ?? UIViewController())

        let signoutParameters = MSALSignoutParameters(webviewParameters: MSALManager.shared.webViewParameters!)

        signoutParameters.signoutFromBrowser = false // set this to true if you also want to signout from browser or webview

        applicationContext.signout(with: account, signoutParameters: signoutParameters, completionBlock: {(success, error) in

            if let error = error {

                return

            }

            MSALManager.shared.accessToken = ""

            MSALManager.shared.originalAuthTokenExpire = nil

            self.timer?.invalidate()

            MSALManager.shared.currentAccount = nil

            self.performLogoutAction()

        })

    }

}
```

Comment: Hello, what class or object is MSALManager? Can you share documentation or source code?

Comment: @AlfredoRevilla-MSFT, added MSAL Manager